# Pragma Mark missing in Xcode SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have written Pragma Mark after @implementation ViewController  in .m file.

But Pragma Mark is not display in .m file whenever i have not synthesized any property. 
Why Xcode is restricting me for doing this ?

Even if other Pragma Marks is displayed. But the Pragma Mark written after @implementation ViewController is not displayed.

If i synthesized any single property after @implementation ViewController,
then the Pragma Mark  is displayed. I am not getting all this fus.

```
@implementation ViewController


# pragma  mark View Life cycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the #pragma code snipped where the error occurs? What version of Xcode?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist : i am using Xcode 4.5.1 :)

Comment: I have updated my answer...have a look :)

Comment: It is indeed missing. You should [file a bug](http://bugreporter.apple.com)

Comment: Appears to be a bug in Xcode 4.5/4.6. First pragma mark never shows. Worked fine in earlier versions.

Comment: And here's a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430469/pragma-mark-not-listing-the-first-group-name

Answer (score 3):

Use in this way:

```
@implementation MainViewController
{}
#pragma YES
#pragma mark - Second -
```

Comment: You don't need to have multiple `#pragma`s like that. Any `-` surrounded by whitespace is turned into a separator e.g. `#pragma mark - First -`. I'm sure it's a stylistic choice but I find the multiline version painful on the eyes

Comment: i use separator to distinguish similar kind of methods like all ioactions, all tableview delgates, all textfield delegate to find it with ease. :)

Comment: @Anoop :  Write #pragma mark exact after " implementation MainViewController " Then check it.

Comment: Ok... Now I got your problem, for the first method you cant set pragma mark.

Comment: Now check the answer...a little bit of tweak.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya : Yes it is working. But why Xcode has behaving like this ? Is there any apple documentation for this ?

Comment: that I dont know, but might be they missed to add there :)

Answer (score -1):

Its may be an Xcode version Problem.

Because in Xcode 4.2 it shows proper.

Comment: Not really i have used Xcode3, 3.1, 3.2, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5... everywere it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

i think it is working for Xcode 4.2. I am not able to do in Xcode 4.5 if i am not writing any synthesized property.

```
@Implementation ViewController

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Init
```

this code doesn't display Init. when i am writing below code in Xcode 4.5

```
@Implementation ViewController

@synthesize txtlabel;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Init
```

above code displays Init, So i think its Xcode problem.

Thanks, Sagar.

Comment: Just to let you know you can abbreviate that to #pragma mark - Init