# #pragma mark not listing the first group name

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, pragma

I'm using `#pragma mark` for grouping my methods under certain categories. But the issue is in `Xcode 4` my first category is not displaying.

My code looks like:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Category 1

//Some method declaration

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Category 2

//Some method declaration

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Category 3

//Some method declaration
@end
```

But when I check on `Xcode` It displays only Category 2 and Category 3. Category 1 is not listed there, please check the Image
[image: Pragma Issue]

Is there any issue in my code or is it a bug in `XCode` ?

Comment: +1 I never noticed this!!

Comment: @borrrden: thanks, anoop's answer fixed this issue. Bug in Xcode also :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes it is a Bug here.

But you can override this bug to your requirement by just adding {} in your  **interface .h file/** as well as in **implementation  / .m file** :

```
@implementation AppDelegate
{}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Category 1

-(void)awakeFromNib{

}
```

Also, no need to use two #pragma, you can combine both of them into one as :

```
#pragma mark - Category 1
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Beat me to it.  It seems that Xcode still expects the old way of writing classes.  Also note that this works for `@interface` as well (which is the code in the OP's question)

Comment: @borrrden: Yes even for .h and .m has the same issue, and in hurry I did in .m ;)

Comment: Just wanted to point it out in case someone felt like saying "Hey, that's the .m file not the .h file!!"

Comment: @borrrden: or should i change the code snippet and screen shot also?

Comment: No, it i fine as it is now!  Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 13):

Another clean way to go : just add a simple `;`.

```
@implementation AppDelegate;

#pragma mark - Category 1
```

Comment: Yes this look better than mine ;)